# What is a good way to route all HTTP requests to a local port?

Tags: ruby, http, proxy, server, bdd

Setting up a server to respond to all HTTP requests for testing.

The goal is to send all HTTP requests to `localhost:3000`. Tried https://github.com/samuelkadolph/ruby-proxifier and https://github.com/igrigorik/em-proxy, but they don't seem to work on Ruby 2.2.0.

Also tried https://evancarmi.com/writing/faraday-proxy/, but it didn't work.

What is a good way to route all HTTP traffic to localhost:3000?

EDIT: I noticed that this question isn't clear. The goal is to route all requests on a machine to a port. These requests would come from a browser or a Ruby app.

Comment: Why don't you just start the server on port 80?

Comment: I want to proxy *all HTTP requests* to that server. For example, `GET http://www.google.com` should be sent to `localhost:3000`.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to route all http requests within a ruby program?

I think [Socksify](http://socksify.rubyforge.org/) can do that.

> ## Installation
>
> $ gem install socksify
>
> ## Usage
>
> ### Redirect all TCP connections of a Ruby program
>
> Run a Ruby script with redirected TCP through a local Tor anonymizer:
>
> $ socksify_ruby localhost 9050 script.rb

Comment: The goal is to redirect all HTTP requests on a machine, not within Ruby. I'll update the question.